# Making web applications more like desktop applications in Firefox

Tags: firefox, web-application

As time goes, I find myself using more and more web applications, and it's great, except for one thing: it would be more convenient to move each app into a separate window with minimal chrome (no toolbars, menubars etc.) and the app's own favicon instead of the Firefox one. Are there currently any add-ons that would allow for this or similar behavior?

Comment: it is a duplicate:[click here](http://superuser.com/questions/468580/create-application-shortcut-chromes-feature-in-firefox).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fear this is a duplicate, but I haven't found it yet.

Anyway to answer your question: [use Prism](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6665)

> [Prism is a simple XULRunner based
>   browser](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebRunner) that hosts web
>   applications without the normal web
>   browser user interface. Prism is based
>   on a concept called Site Specific
>   Browsers (SSB). An SSB is an
>   application with an embedded browser
>   designed to work exclusively with a
>   single web application. It doesn’t
>   have the menus, toolbars and
>   accoutrements of a normal web browser.
>   Some people have called it a
>   "distraction free browser" because
>   none of the typical browser chrome is
>   used. An SSB also has a tighter
>   integration with the OS and desktop
>   than a typical web application running
>   through a web browser.

[image]

> **[Features](http://prism.mozilla.com/)**
>
> **- Access web apps from system
>   taskbar or dock**
>
> Prism apps run directly on your
>   desktop and can be accessed just like
>   any other application
>
> **- Rock solid web app stability**
>
> Prism apps run separately from the
>   browser, so they stay up even if your
>   browser doesn't
>
> **- System tray icon and dock badges**
>
> On Windows, the system tray icon can
>   be changed to give information about
>   application

Comment: This seems like it could be unexpectedly good, thanks.