# Firefox equivalent of : google-chrome --app=http://website.com

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, web-application

A specific website can be launched in Google Chrome without any visible interface (navigation bar, tabs or menus) using the command : google-chrome --app=http://website.com

Is there an equivalent for Firefox ?

EDIT : A 4 years old superuser post [’Create application shortcut…' Chrome's feature in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/468580/create-application-shortcut-chromes-feature-in-firefox?rq=1) mentions some possible solutions

- Mozilla Prism : discontinued
- firefox.exe -chrome http://superuser.com : not working anymore
- Standalone (Firefox addon) : not compatible with Firefox 48

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has a Kiosk mode. The source article says this is for Enterprise but it worked in my normal installation of Firefox.

You can launch it with command:

`firefox.exe -kiosk -private-window [target URL]`

Source: [Firefox Enterprise Kiosk mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-enterprise-kiosk-mode)

The `-private-window` flag is not necessary but I've added it to prevent interference with any other Firefox sessions.

**Note:** It is still possible to open a new tab and therefore navigate to other pages.

To prevent such actions, you can use [policies](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mKiosk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mkiosk/). When installed, it should give you a setup screen. This will have a navigation bar by default, but it should be able to be disabled.